# How to combine django "prefetch_related" and "values" methods?

Tags: python, django

**How can `prefetch_related` and `values` method be applied in combination?**

Previously, I had the following code. Limiting fields in this query is required for performance optimization.

```py
Organizations.objects.values('id','name').order_by('name')
```

Now, I need to prefetch its association and append it in the serializer using "prefetch_related" method.

```py
Organizations.objects.prefetch_related('locations').order_by('name')
```

Here, I cannot seem to find a way to limit the fields after using "prefetch_related".

I have tried the following, but on doing so serializer does not see the associated "locations".

```py
Organizations.objects.prefetch_related('locations').values("id", "name").order_by('name')
```

Model Skeleton:

```py
class Organizations(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organizations, to_field="name", db_column="organization_name", related_name='locations')

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'locations'
```

Comment: Maybe this: `Organizations.objects.prefetch_related('locations').values("locations__id", "locations__name").order_by('locations__name')` ?

Comment: @nik_m: Nope, it is not working. I am getting this error.
Cannot resolve keyword 'locations' into field

Comment: Hmm... It's working perfectly fine for me. `locations` is the `related_name` given to the other model, right? What are the available options of choices that you get?

Answer (score 9):

Use `only()` to limit number of fields retrieved if you're concerned about your app performances. See [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only).

In the example above, this would be:

```
Organizations.objects.prefetch_related('locations').only('id', 'name').order_by('name')
```

which would result in two queries:

```
SELECT id, name FROM organizations;
SELECT * from locations WHERE organization_name = <whatever is seen before>;
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide a full example. How exactly would you use `only()` with `prefetch_related()`?

Comment: Just use `only()` in lieu of `value()` as per the example above. 

`value()` is incorrectly used in this question and is intended to be used for [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values) or [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) purposes, in conjunction with `annotate()`. 

When used alone `value()` also mimics `only()` by selecting specific fields, thus the confusion.

Comment: In Django 4.1 with Postgres, I needed to additionally select the foreign key of the prefetched object, otherwise Django was doing a DB lookup for each prefetched object to select the foreign key (which is worse than no prefetch at all).