# Prefetch querysets cannot use values

Tags: python, django, orm

i want to make the follow query for get a queryset with this characteristic:

1. pre-filtered
2. grouped by name
3. sum the inner data

in my code i have:

```
q = DatiBanca.objects\
   .filter(is_negativo=False)\
   .values("istituto_credito__name")\
   .order_by("istituto_credito__name")

anagrafiche = anagrafiche.prefetch_related(
   Prefetch('dati__banche', queryset=q)
)
```

dataset JSON:

```
"dataset": {
    "id": 40,
    "banche": [
        {
        "id": 18396,
        "name": "Pippo",
        "importo": "10",
        "istituto_credito": 3,
        "is_negativo": false
        },
        {
        "id": 18397,
        "name": "Pippo",
        "importo": "20",
        "istituto_credito": 3,
        "is_negativo": false
        },
        {
        "id": 18398,
        "name": "Pippo",
        "importo": "999999999999",
        "istituto_credito": 3,
        "is_negativo": true
        },
        {
        "id": 16519,
        "name": "Pluto",
        "importo": "40",
        "istituto_credito": 5,
        "is_negativo": false
        },
        {
        "id": 13967,
        "name": "Paperino",
        "importo": "50",
        "istituto_credito": 4,
        "is_negativo": false
        }
    ]
}
```

this query give me belows error:

**"Prefetch querysets cannot use values()."**

how can i get following result from dataset?

```
"dataset": {
    "id": 40,
    "banche": [
        {
        "name": "Pippo",
        "importo": "30",
        "istituto_credito": 3,
        "is_negativo": false
        }
        {
        "name": "Pluto",
        "importo": "40",
        "istituto_credito": 5,
        "is_negativo": false
        },
        {
        "name": "Paperino",
        "importo": "50",
        "istituto_credito": 4,
        "is_negativo": false
        }
    ]
}
```

[this example: How to combine django “prefetch_related” and “values” methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054459/how-to-combine-django-prefetch-related-and-values-methods)
 dont' use a Prefetch function and limit the result to one field. I want perform a group by operation on sub-queryset of Anagrafica

I use
django 2.1.5

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the values() call on the original query, like this:

```
q = DatiBanca.objects\
   .filter(is_negativo=False)\
   .order_by("istituto_credito__name")

anagrafiche = anagrafiche.prefetch_related(
   Prefetch('dati__banche', queryset=q)
)
```

And now each object in `anagrafiche` is a `DatiBlanca` object, with `DatiBlanca.dati.banche` prefetched. You can then list the values of `DatiBlanca.istituto_credito.name` later from this queryset.

Comment: Now i have removed values() call and "group by" operation i will perform client side.
To optimize the query i need values() call for group by the result

Comment: I got an idea from: https://medium.com/@lucasmagnum/djangotip-select-prefetch-related-e76b683aa457 , you can use Pretech and F methods:
`q = DatiBanca.objects.filter(is_negativo=False).annotate(name=F("istituto_credito__name")).order_by("istituto_credito__name")`

`anagrafiche = anagrafiche.prefetch_related(Prefetch('dati__banche', queryset=q, to_attr='datibanca_objs'))`
then you can access to "istituto_credito__name" using "name" attribute

`for anag in anagrafiche:\ for obj in anag.datibanca_objs:\  print(obj.name)`
... reducing queries to database.